# imageview new width and height apply on screen rotation only

Tags: android

Hi I have a simple FrameLayout with an ImageView.
I can programmatically set its coordinates using setX and setY methods, and it works fine, but when I try to set a new size using

```
myImageView.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;
myImageView.getLayoutParams().width = newWidth;
```

the size is not set until a screen rotation happens.
Note, that I have

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

attribute in my manifest file, if I remove it, it works as expected, the new width/height are set instantly.
How can I solve this issue without removing that attribute from the manifest?

Comment: Try calling `myImageView.invalidate()` after changing the height and width

Comment: Alternatively try `myImageView.requestLayout()`

Comment: Tried, but doesn't work, same behaviour...